# Calculate new value based on decreasing value

Tags: python, pandas

**Problem:**

What'd I like to do is step-by-step reduce a value in a `Series` by a continuously decreasing base figure.

I'm not sure of the terminology for this - I did think I could do something with `cumsum` and `diff` but I think I'm leading myself on a wild goose chase there...

**Starting code:**

```
import pandas as pd

ALLOWANCE = 100
values = pd.Series([85, 10, 25, 30])
```

**Desired output:**

```
desired = pd.Series([0, 0, 20, 30])
```

**Rationale:**

Starting with a base of `ALLOWANCE` - each value in the `Series` is reduced by the amount remaining, as is the allowance itself, so the following steps occur:

- Start with 100, we can completely remove `85` so it becomes `0`, we now have `15` left as `ALLOWANCE`
- The next value is `10` and we still have `15` available, so this becomes `0` again and we have `5` left.
- The next value is `25` - we only have `5` left, so this becomes `20` and now we have no further allowance.
- The next value is `30`, and since there's no allowance, the value remains as `30`.

Comment: I would rename the `values` variable into `expenses` and the `desired` variable into `debts`, which in combination with `allowance` makes the reader understand what you are trying to accomplish without even looking at the text, imo.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Following your initial idea of `cumsum` and `diff`, you could write:

```
>>> (values.cumsum() - ALLOWANCE).clip_lower(0).diff().fillna(0)
0     0
1     0
2    20
3    30
dtype: float64
```

This is the cumulative sum of `values` minus the allowance. Negative values are clipped to zeros (since we don't care about numbers until we have overdrawn our allowance). From there, you can calculate the difference.

However, if the first value might be greater than the allowance, the following two-line variation is preferred:

```
s = (values.cumsum() - ALLOWANCE).clip_lower(0)
desired = s.diff().fillna(s)
```

This fills the first `NaN` value with the "first value - allowance" value. So in the case where `ALLOWANCE` is lowered to 75, it returns `desired` as `Series([10, 10, 25, 30])`.

Comment: This doesn't appear to handle where the first element of the `Series` > `ALLOWANCE` :(

Comment: @JonClements you just need to append `.fillna(0)`

Comment: @EdChum cant' do that - think I need to use similar to Carsten's answer, if the first value in the series remains `85`, and the `ALLOWANCE` is 70, the result is `0` - which is incorrect - it should be `15`

Comment: I've gone for a hybrid between yours and Carsten's answer - I like the `clip_lower()` in this one, even though Carsten was the first to point out that `.fillna(0)` would yield incorrect results. (although you have corrected that - thanks)

Answer (score 8):

Your idea with `cumsum` and `diff` works. It doesn't look too complicated; not sure if there's an even shorter solution. First, we compute the cumulative sum, operate on that, and then go back (`diff` is kinda sorta the inverse function of `cumsum`).

```
import math

c = values.cumsum() - ALLOWANCE
# now we've got [-15, -5, 20, 50]
c[c < 0] = 0 # negative values don't make sense here

# (c - c.shift(1)) # <-- what I had first: diff by accident

# it is important that we don't fill with 0, in case that the first
# value is greater than ALLOWANCE
c.diff().fillna(math.max(0, values[0] - ALLOWANCE))
```

Answer (score 5):

This is probably not so performant but at the moment this is a Pandas way of doing this using [`rolling_apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.rolling_apply.html#pandas.rolling_apply):

```
In [53]:

ALLOWANCE = 100
def reduce(x):
    global ALLOWANCE
    # short circuit if we've already reached 0
    if ALLOWANCE == 0:
        return x
    val = max(0, x - ALLOWANCE)
    ALLOWANCE = max(0, ALLOWANCE - x)
    return val

pd.rolling_apply(values, window=1, func=reduce)
Out[53]:
0     0
1     0
2    20
3    30
dtype: float64
```

Or more simply:

```
In [58]:

values.apply(reduce)
Out[58]:
0     0
1     0
2    20
3    30
dtype: int64
```

Comment: There is likely a better way to rewrite my function, I'm not a python expert, I was thinking that this could be rewritten using a generator but it didn't quite work for some reason. Ideally I'd short circuit this if the allowance is already 0 and return the passed in row value

Comment: It's certainly pointed me in what looks like the right direction and given me some ideas... thanks for very much - reading up on `rolling_apply` now

Answer (score 1):

It should work with a `while` loop :

```
ii = 0
while (ALLOWANCE > 0 and ii < len(values)):
    if (ALLOWANCE > values[ii]):
        ALLOWANCE -= values[ii]
        values[ii] = 0
    else:
        values[ii] -= ALLOWANCE
        ALLOWANCE = 0
    ii += 1
```

Comment: Thanks. While this will work, I'm also planning on doing other operations in `pandas` - so I'm really after a `pandas` based solution if possible.