# Splitting number into bands for variable rate billing, ie "tiered pricing"

Tags: python, algorithm, billing

I have a problem that's simple on paper, but I'm struggling to work out in code. Before I go any further, **this is not a string splitting question**.

I have what is essentially a banded timesheet application. The scale is variable based on client but an example is the first three hours in a month are 80, the next three hours are 70 and remainder are 50. I currently represent this in code as:

```
scale = [80, 80, 80, 70, 70, 70, 50]
```

... But I'm open to suggestions there too.

The scale and number of steps are —and have to be— variable. Some of my billing is much more simple with some clients but I like to be able to offer this high-usage plan.

But how do I take a number of hours worked (eg 15.2) and calculate how much they should be paying? How do I split this big number into bands? As I say, it's been easy enough to work out on paper but as I get more clients and more convoluted schemes, that's getting pretty boring. Here's how I would work it out for 15.2 hours:

```
3 hours at 80 = 240
3 hours at 70 = 210
9.2 hours at 50 = 460
total = 910
```

While I'm at it, I'd appreciate comments for the proper names for what I'm trying to describe. And Oli, if you've landed back here in 2023, pick an easier billing scheme next time, mate.

Comment: Looks like an extension to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28676916/calculate-new-value-based-on-decreasing-value...

Comment: Thanks @JonClements. It looks *similar* but doesn't quite seem to do the same thing. I'm a bit frazzled today to feel free to correct me there! I've added a paper-calculation to show the logic I'm after.

Comment: I'd suggest if there are many different steps, with different rules - not to try and create a generic "fits all" solution. While it might use less code and feel "more flexible", it could end up being a maintenance nightmare once you forget why certain rules are there. Instead, surely just a separate function for each payment scheme will be easiest. After that, just running through hour by hour in a loop and then calculating the last fraction (i.e. the naive way) will likely be best as you can spend more  time actually making product and not figuring out billing formulas.

Comment: Yeah... I was using that to do "free allowance" (imagine mobile number packages), and then the rest of the balance at N rate... so it's the same thing... but reducing each stage with boundaries sort of... I'll have a dig around to see if I've got the final code I implemented (100 mins free, then 25p per min for next 10 mins, then 15p for next etc... or whatever the rules were) - have a feeling I might have scrapped it for a simpler method/some existing thing I had access to

Comment: (Still hunting a definition) I guess this is similar to complex "volume pricing" tables (units 1-3 at 80, units 4-6 at 70, and 7+ are 50/each) but I allow fractional units. Edit: [Chargebee says this is Tiered Pricing](https://www.chargebee.com/usecase-guides/tiered-pricing/) and it's different from volume pricing, which is based on the total quantity.

Comment: @Oli I think your example is wrong, the total is 910 not 940.

Comment: @PacoH.  The other reason I need to automate this: I'm an idiot who can't add up.

Answer (score 3):

First, I would turn this:

```
scale = [80, 80, 80, 70, 70, 70, 50]
```

Into this:

```
import math

scale = {(0, 3): 80, (3, 6): 70, (6, math.inf): 50}
```

Then the rest of my algorithm follows:

```
# Total hours worked
hours_worked = 15.2

# Handle the decimal (if any) to begin with... First find the "max" rate
decimal_rate = next(rate for (lower, upper), rate in scale.items()
                        if lower <= hours_worked and upper >= hours_worked)

# Then calculate the last "sliver" of pay
decimal_end = hours_worked - int(hours_worked)
end_pay = decimal_end * decimal_rate

# Use an integer for ease of calculation
hours_worked = int(hours_worked)

hours_paid_for = 0

# Beginning total pay is just the decimal "ending"
total_pay = end_pay

while hours_paid_for < hours_worked:
    # Find the rate for the current bucket of hours
    rate_filter = (rate for (lower, upper), rate in scale.items() if lower <= hours_paid_for and hours_paid_for < upper)
    current_level = next(rate_filter)

    print('Hour: {}'.format(hours_paid_for))
    print('Pay rate: ${}'.format(current_level))

    total_pay += current_level

    hours_paid_for += 1

print('Total earned: ${}'.format(total_pay))
```

Output follows:

```
Hour: 0
Pay rate: $80
Hour: 1
Pay rate: $80
Hour: 2
Pay rate: $80
Hour: 3
Pay rate: $70
Hour: 4
Pay rate: $70
Hour: 5
Pay rate: $70
Hour: 6
Pay rate: $50
Hour: 7
Pay rate: $50
Hour: 8
Pay rate: $50
Hour: 9
Pay rate: $50
Hour: 10
Pay rate: $50
Hour: 11
Pay rate: $50
Hour: 12
Pay rate: $50
Hour: 13
Pay rate: $50
Hour: 14
Pay rate: $50
Total earned: $910.0
```

Here's a nice-and-neat function, too:

```
def calculate_pay(scale, hours_worked):

    # Handle the decimal (if any) to begin with... First find the "max" rate
    decimal_rate = next(rate for (lower, upper), rate in scale.items()
                            if lower <= hours_worked and upper >= hours_worked)

    # Then calculate the last "sliver" of pay
    decimal_end = hours_worked - int(hours_worked)
    end_pay = decimal_end * decimal_rate

    # Use an integer for ease of calculation
    hours_worked = int(hours_worked)

    # Hours already paid for (int)
    hours_paid_for = 0

    # Beginning 'total pay' can be the decimal end, if any
    total_pay = end_pay

    while hours_paid_for < hours_worked:
        # Find the rate for the current bucket of hours
        rate_filter = (rate for (lower, upper), rate in scale.items()
                        if lower <= hours_paid_for and hours_paid_for < upper)
        current_level = next(rate_filter)

        total_pay += current_level

        hours_paid_for += 1

    return total_pay
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the problem correctly here is my try. It's not compact, but I prefer readable. I changed the bands representation to `[(hours, price), (hours, price), ... (None, Price)]`, see example below:

```
def calculate_cost(hours, bands):
    remaining_hours = hours
    current_band_idx = 0
    total_cost = 0

    while remaining_hours > 0:
        band_max_hours, band_cost = bands[current_band_idx]

        if band_max_hours is None:
            band_billable_hours = remaining_hours
        else:
            band_billable_hours = min(remaining_hours, band_max_hours)

        total_cost += band_billable_hours * band_cost
        current_band_idx += 1
        remaining_hours -= band_billable_hours

    return total_cost
```

And for your example:

```
>>> calculate_cost(15.2, [(3, 80), (3, 70), (None, 50)])
910.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Although in my comment I suggested going for the simplest/most naive approach and just looping through - my curiosity got the better of me and so here is a "less lines" approach using recursion.

Starting with a list of "cost buckets", each comprising of a price for a set numbers of hours (e.g. [3,80] => 3 hours at 80 price units), you can break down your hours until you have filled each bucket in order (or have reached the final bucket where all remaining hours are 'spent').

```
# each bucket is a pair of [max hours at this rate, rate per hour]
def calc_cost(cost_buckets: list, hours_worked):
    if hours_worked <= cost_buckets[0][0] or len(cost_buckets) < 2:
        return cost_buckets[0][1] * hours_worked
    return calc_cost(cost_buckets, cost_buckets[0][0]) + calc_cost(cost_buckets[1:], hours_worked - cost_buckets[0][0])


hours = 2.5 # number of hours total worked
costs = [[1,12], [5,30]] # list of 'cost buckets'
print(calc_cost(costs, hours)) # prints '57.0'
```

It's an inflexible approach, but it'll do what you're after specifically.

(I should obviously point out the usual issues with recursion; in that if you're thinking of having a 100,000 work hour plan with 20,000 cost buckets - you might not want to do this.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach, using the rate storage scheme you used first. **This approach assumes that the number of hours worked on a project is at least as long as the number of rates in `s` (i.e. `len(s)`)**!

```
# Original rate scaling method
s = [80, 80, 80, 70, 70, 70, 50]

hours_worked = 15.2

final_hours_rate = s[-1]

# Handle the "decimal end"
end_pay = (hours_worked - int(hours_worked)) * final_hours_rate

hours_worked = int(hours_worked)

n_rates = len(s)

remainder = sum(s[hour] for hour in range(n_rates)) + \
            final_hours_rate * (hours_worked - n_rates)

total_pay = end_pay + remainder
```

`total_pay` is 910.

Comment: I like the idea but if I'm following this correctly, this only works the hours worked are longer than the scale. The decimal portion gets charged at the next rate, not always the last rate.

Comment: For example, 1.2 hours here would return 90. It should be 96.